# Change D3 forced directed graph node radius based on indegree

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I have a D3 forced directed graph implemented with the data being as follows:

```
 {
    "nodes": [{
        "name": "A",
        "group": 9
    }, {
        "name": "B",
        "group": 1
    }, {
        "name": "C",
        "group": 6
    }, {
        "name": "D",
        "group": 7
    }],
    "links": [{
        "source": 0,
        "target": 0,
        "value": 5
    }, {
        "source": 0,
        "target": 1,
        "value": 25
    }, {
        "source": 2,
        "target": 3,
        "value": 10
    }]
  }
```

I'm trying to have the node radius be determined by the indegree (and/or outdegree) for each node. I tried doing this in my JS:

```
var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
            .data(graph.nodes)
            .enter().append("circle")
            .attr("class", "node")           
            .attr("r", function (d) {
                return (d.value);
            })
            .style("fill", function (d) {
                return color(d.group);
            })                
            .on('dblclick', connectedNodes);
```

But with the radius code in place, I see no nodes at all. How do I make the node size dependent on the value?

Comment: You would need to add the degree information to the nodes first. At the moment, you only have it for the links.

Comment: did you get it to work? I am just struggling with the part of adding the degree information to the node.